# map single object from JSON array to new JSON list.

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, properties

I have a JSON Array of objects like:

```
$scope.people = [
  {id: 1, forename: 'Bob', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '01/01/1990', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 2, forename: 'Bill', surname: 'Billster', DOB: '01/12/1999', address: '56 Road'},
  {id: 3, forename: 'Sally', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '15/04/1987', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 4, forename: 'Flerp', surname: 'Derp', DOB: '01/09/1991', address: '34 Derpington'}
];
```

but I need to extract a single record (and specific fields) to its own list based on a value, in this case the id.

I've used .map before, but that will make a new array of all records but lets me specify field, I'm not aware of a way I can filter at this point

```
specificFields = RawData.map(function (el) {
  return ({
    surname: el['surname'].replace(/ /g, ''),
    DOB: el['DOB'].replace(/ /g, '')
    })
 })
```

I'm not sure how to extract one record based on a single value, as in my case the id will always be unique, but if its not how would a process expecting 1 record handle it when I need it as a single list not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only transforming the `array` elements here, without  selecting the right `object`.

What you need to do is to **filter** the `array` first using **[`.filter()`method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**, then transform the result with **[`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**:

```
const specificFields = RawData.filter(e => e.id === id).map(function (el) {
  return ({
    surname: el['surname'].replace(/ /g, ''),
    DOB: el['DOB'].replace(/ /g, '')
    });
 });
```

**Demo:**

```js
const RawData = [
  {id: 1, forename: 'Bob', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '01/01/1990', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 2, forename: 'Bill', surname: 'Billster', DOB: '01/12/1999', address: '56 Road'},
  {id: 3, forename: 'Sally', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '15/04/1987', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 4, forename: 'Flerp', surname: 'Derp', DOB: '01/09/1991', address: '34 Derpington'}
];

const id = 2;

const specificFields = RawData.filter(e => e.id === id).map(function (el) {
  return ({
    surname: el['surname'].replace(/ /g, ''),
    DOB: el['DOB'].replace(/ /g, '')
    });
 });
 
 console.log(specificFields);
```

### If the `id` is not unique:

If the `id` is not unique, you will need to check over the whole `object` properties, you can do that using **[`.every()`method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** over the properties of each iterated object inside `filter()` callback:

```
const specificFields = RawData.filter(e => Object.keys(e).every(k => e[k] == person[k])).map(function (el) {
  return ({
    surname: el['surname'].replace(/ /g, ''),
    DOB: el['DOB'].replace(/ /g, '')
    });
 });
```

**Demo:**

```js
const RawData = [
  {id: 1, forename: 'Bob', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '01/01/1990', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 2, forename: 'Bill', surname: 'Billster', DOB: '01/12/1999', address: '56 Road'},
  {id: 3, forename: 'Sally', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '15/04/1987', address: '123 Fake St'},
  {id: 4, forename: 'Flerp', surname: 'Derp', DOB: '01/09/1991', address: '34 Derpington'}
];

const person = {id: 4, forename: 'Flerp', surname: 'Derp', DOB: '01/09/1991', address: '34 Derpington'};
 
const specificFields = RawData.filter(e => Object.keys(e).every(k => e[k] == person[k])).map(function (el) {
  return ({
    surname: el['surname'].replace(/ /g, ''),
    DOB: el['DOB'].replace(/ /g, '')
    });
 });
 
 console.log(specificFields);
```

Comment: Why does he needs to map it?

Comment: because hew wants only specific fields from the object as he said.

Comment: I didn't pay attention about the specific fields (it was in bracket - like optional)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate JSON array and filter by ID as below -

```
angular.forEach($scope.people, function(people) {
  if(people.id == filterID){
    // your code goes here
    console.log(people);
  }
});
```

If the ID is not unique then you will get multiple records in array with same ID and you should put business logic/validation to handle/reject it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)?

```js
    var people = [
      {id: 1, forename: 'Bob', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '01/01/1990', address: '123 Fake St'},
      {id: 2, forename: 'Bill', surname: 'Billster', DOB: '01/12/1999', address: '56 Road'},
      {id: 3, forename: 'Sally', surname: 'Bobbington', DOB: '15/04/1987', address: '123 Fake St'},
      {id: 4, forename: 'Flerp', surname: 'Derp', DOB: '01/09/1991', address: '34 Derpington'}
    ];

    let result = people.filter(person => person .id == 3);
    console.log(result);
```

Otherwise you can use the [angularjs $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

- **PS 1**: I use simple `var` (not `$scope` so you can see result in snipet).
- **PS 2**: If you wan't also to return specifics fields so you will have to map the return value (refer to [chŝdk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316504/1811956))